# How to hide help content in an eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In my eclipse based RCP Application, I want to hide unwanted help contents.
[image: Screenshot]

The help content is added via the `org.eclipse.help.toc` extension point from other plug-ins.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.help.toc">
    <toc file="help/toc.xml" primary="true">
    </toc>
</extension>
```

I tried to disable it by activities:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
    <activity id="disable" name="Disable">
    </activity>
    <activityPatternBinding activityId="disable"
            pattern=".*/org.eclipse.help.toc">
    </activityPatternBinding>
</extension>
```

But no success.

Comment: Why do you include the plug-ins that provide the help content in the first place? Wouldn't it be easier to omit the unwanted help plug-ins from the product or feature that you deploy?

Comment: I need the other stuff from that plug-in.

Comment: If, for example, you exclude the `org.eclipse.jdt.doc.*` plug-ins from the runtime the corresponding TOC entries will vanish. I don't see any other _stuff_ they provide. Or am I missing tsomething here?

Comment: If help content contributions could be controlled by activities - which they cannot to my knowledge - the `pattern` would have to be something like `pattern="org\.eclipse\.jdt\.doc\..*/.*"`. The pattern must match the id of the contribution and not the extension point id.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann +1 for your comment add your comment as answer.I think activities not required.

Comment: The help content is contributed by a 3rd party plug-in, which contains not only help content. Simple exclude the plug-in is NOT an option.

Comment: I can modify the plugin xml file in the 3rd party plugin jar. But that is are very dirty method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help content contributions cannot be controlled by activities.

You simply need to  exclude the help plug-ins (e.g. `org.eclipse.jdt.doc.*` for JDT documentation) from the runtime and the corresponding TOC entries will vanish.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. As I mention in my question: _"I try to disable then by activities. Without success."_ I found out already that "Help content contributions cannot be controlled by activities." I also need other contributions from this plug-in. Exclude the plug-in is NOT an option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found the solution. You have to set the content to be hidden with HELP_DATA ([link)](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help_setup_help_data.htm).

Here's my helpData.xml content:

```
<extensions>
   <hidden>
      <toc id="/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/toc.xml"/>
   </hidden>
</extensions>
```

and then refer to it in plugin_customization.ini:

```
org.eclipse.help/HELP_DATA = helpData.xml
```

and reference your plugin_customization.ini in your eclipse.ini or in the vm arguments of your launch config as

-Declipse.pluginCustomization=${workspace_loc}/com.castortech.iris.vision/plugin_customization.ini